# How to remove double qoutes from json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova

I am working on `cordova`. From a `php` script i have generated a `json` data. Below is my json data

```
 "11111111": [
    { "x": "2016-01-25 12:58:52", "y": "25.22" },
    { "x": "2016-01-26 13:33:23", "y": "30.14" },
    { "x": "2016-01-27 13:49:18", "y": "35.58" },
    { "x": "2016-01-29 13:55:01", "y": "40.25" },
    { "x": "2016-01-30 14:00:15", "y": "47.25" },
    { "x": "2016-01-31 15:50:15", "y": "14.25" },
    { "x": "2016-02-01 16:16:15", "y": "20.25" },
    { "x": "2016-02-02 17:49:15", "y": "5.25" },
    { "x": "2016-02-03 18:20:15", "y": "77.25" },
    { "x": "2016-02-04 19:30:15", "y": "65.25" }
],
```

But i want to remove the `double quotes` from the `y` data i.e.

```
 "11111111": [
    { "x": "2016-01-25 12:58:52", "y": 25.22 },
    { "x": "2016-01-26 13:33:23", "y": 30.14 },
    { "x": "2016-01-27 13:49:18", "y": 35.58 },
    { "x": "2016-01-29 13:55:01", "y": 40.25 },
    { "x": "2016-01-30 14:00:15", "y": 47.25 },
    { "x": "2016-01-31 15:50:15", "y": 14.25 },
    { "x": "2016-02-01 16:16:15", "y": 20.25 },
    { "x": "2016-02-02 17:49:15", "y": 5.25 },
    { "x": "2016-02-03 18:20:15", "y": 77.25 },
    { "x": "2016-02-04 19:30:15", "y": 65.25 }
],
```

**Updated Code:**

Below is my script from which i have generated json

```
if($result)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $serial = $row['Device_Serial_Number'];
    $x = $row['Data_Datetime'];
    $y = $row['Energy_kwh'];

    if(!isset($data[$serial]))
    {
        $data[$serial] = [];
    }
    $data[$serial][] = ['x' => $x , 'y' => $y];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}

$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo "var jsonData = " . $json;
```

I searched many articles but couldn't find any good solution

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You should have a look at where `$y` is created. It is currently a string within PHP, so the best approach would be to change this at creation time. Currently you do not share code related to the creation of `$x` and `$y`.

Comment: A quick fix would be to cast it to float in case you get a string back from a database: `'y' => (float) $y`

Comment: @Sirko please see the update

Comment: @jeroen yes it's working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a string back from a database or a `$_POST` value, you can cast it to float:

```
$data[$serial][] = ['x' => $x , 'y' => (float) $y];
```

Comment: Working perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

When the you created the json data, $y is float data type, and when your php script generated the data you should make sure that the precision of the float data type not replaced by string

you can use option for json_encode

```
JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
```

its different for each php version
you should check the manual

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

but it does not matter if setter getter in your cordova can handle it, you can cast to float when your app get data from your php script even if your script return it as string.

sorry for bad english